# Issue in converting a stored procedure to NSString

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sql-server

In an iPhone App I've written, I connect to a web service for executing SQL Server stored procedures. I sent some simple queries, it works fine.

I tried some simple stored procedures, yes, again it works well. The issue is with this particular stored procedure's conversion to NSString. I realize am missing adding an escape character for some specific character. I've added escape characters for square brackets '[]', and for '%'. Am saying that escape characters is the issue because the error am getting after execution is saying 'syntax error in the stored procedure'.

But when I execute this directly in the DB (i.e. locally through SQL command-line client), am not getting any error ... it works fine. So, seems to be an issue when converting it to NSString. Please help.

```
DECLARE @ts_now bigint = (SELECT cpu_ticks/(cpu_ticks/ms_ticks) FROM sys.dm_os_sys_info);
SELECT TOP(10) SQLProcessUtilization AS \\[SQL Server Process CPU Utilization\\], 
               SystemIdle AS \\[System Idle Process\\], 
               100 - SystemIdle - SQLProcessUtilization AS \\[Other Process CPU Utilization\\], 
               DATEADD(ms, -1 * (@ts_now - \\[timestamp\\]), GETDATE()) AS \\[Event Time\\]
FROM ( 
      SELECT record.value('(./Record/@id)\\[1\\]', 'int') AS record_id, 
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/SystemIdle)\\[1\\]', 'int') 
            AS \\[SystemIdle\\],
            record.value('(./Record/SchedulerMonitorEvent/SystemHealth/ProcessUtilization)\\[1\\]', 
            'int') 
            AS \\[SQLProcessUtilization\\], \\[timestamp\\] 
      FROM (
            SELECT \\[timestamp\\], convert(xml, record) AS \\[record\\] 
            FROM sys.dm_os_ring_buffers 
            WHERE ring_buffer_type = N'RING_BUFFER_SCHEDULER_MONITOR' 
            AND record LIKE '%%<SystemHealth>%%') AS x 
      ) AS y 
ORDER BY record_id DESC;
```

Am getting an error saying the syntax is wrong. I read this stored procedure into a NSString object and then send the NSString to the web service like this :

```
NSError *error;
NSString *txtFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Proc_Usage" ofType:@"txt"];
NSString *procUsage = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:txtFilePath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
if (procUsage == nil) {
    return -1;
}
[[DbConnect DbConnect_Singleton] executeInDb:procUsage];
```

Comment: Didn't you check what you receive on your server, and what you execute there?  It should be fairly simply to so the difference between original SQL and what you use on the server.

Comment: I did try to see that. But SQL Server logs (in Management Studio) list only locally executed queries (tried searching in system tables too, in vain).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried it without any escaping at all? I don't see why it should need any escaping at all, given that you are reading the string from a file - it's not like it's a string literal.

Comment: True, James. In fact, initially I did try it without any escaping. But that gave syntax error (though when I execute the exact same script locally in the DB, it works fine. Also, executing few other stored procedures work fine programmatically). That's when I thought that maybe it has to do with introducing some escape characters. Do you say it is treated as-is, and not as a string literal?

Comment: Yes, I'm almost certain it should be treated as-is. One thing I've just noticed that might be an issue, though, is that you have two commands in the one query. You might want to try splitting those up, or embedding the ts_now query inline rather than as a separate variable declaration.

Comment: Thanks @James Holderness ; Let me try and get back.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the double percents are being read as a single percent.  Can you try changing:

```
LIKE '%%<SystemHealth>%%'
```

to

```
LIKE '%%%%<SystemHealth>%%%%'
```

Comment: thanks @danh . It's actually only single %. I have put double % just as an escape character. What I want actually is only single %